# Thunderbird extension unexpectedly stops execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, thunderbird-addon, thunderbird-webextensions

Something strange is happening in an extension I'm building in Thunderbird. I've pinpointed it to a very specific example. This example works fine in a regular node.js environment, but in Thunderbird it simply stops execution at a random point in time (looks like it's time dependent).

I'm using an await command inside a for loop, but the for loop never reaches the end. If I remove the await command, it works fine.

I'm thinking there might be some sort of a limitation of time with the MailExtensions API? Not sure what to do here.

This is the code:

```
  async function load() {
    let tmp;
    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      console.log(`i: ${i}, before the await`);
      tmp = await resolveAfterTimeout();
      console.log(`i: ${i}, after the await`);
    };
    console.log('done');
  }

  function resolveAfterTimeout() {
    console.log('inside timeout');
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      console.log('inside new Promise');
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('inside setTimeout');
        resolve('resolved');
      }, 100);
    });
  }
```

Console Output (end):

```
i: 5, after the await
i: 6, before the await
inside timeout
inside new Promise
inside setTimeout
i: 6, after the await
i: 7, before the await
inside timeout
inside new Promise
inside setTimeout
i: 7, after the await
i: 8, before the await
inside timeout
inside new Promise
Webconsole context has changed
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the help of the amazing thunderbird forum chat members! Looks like it's completely my fault - the extension is activated by a popup and runs while the popup is open. I would click on a button to open the popup and switch to the console to see the output, while actually closing the popup and being surprised why the execution stops:)